# How can I create a UNIQUE constraint involving logic on two properties with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have class like this one:

```
public class Link
{
     public virtual long Id { get; set; }
     public virtual string IdentifierA { get; set; }
     public virtual string IdentifierB { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapping like this one:

```
public class LinkMap : ClassMap<Link>
{
    public LinkMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.IdentifierA);
        Map(x => x.IdentifierB);
    }
}
```

I would like to store only links, A, where there no link, B, in the database such that:

```
((A.IdentifierA == B.IndentifierA && A.IdentifierB == B.IdentifierB) || (A.IdentifierA == B.IndentifierB && A.IdentifierB == B.IdentifierA))
```

that is I consider any two links between two given identifiers as the same link, and only want to store one of them.

Can I set that up with Fluent NHibernate? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a database unique constraint

```
Map(x => x.IdentifierA).UniqueKey("Identifier_key");
Map(x => x.IdentifierB).UniqueKey("Identifier_key");
```

But in your scenario i think its better handled in code in one place. select if there exists an entity with the specified conditions and return it instead of saving a new one.

Comment: That mapping gets me half of the way, but does not disallow the situation where old.IdentifierA == new.IdentifierB && old.IdentifierB == new.IdentifierA. I have a solution in code working, as you recommend. Seems like I'll stick with that. Thanks for your answer!